# How to Remove first few lines/header from multiple files using scala in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I was able to remove the first few lines of a single file using the code below:

```
scala> val file = sc.textFile("file:///root/path/file.csv")
```

Removing first 5 lines:

```
 scala> val Data = file.mapPartitionsWithIndex{ (idx, iter) => if (idx == 0) iter.drop(5) else iter }
```

The problem is: Suppose that I have multiple files with the same columns, and I want to load all of them into rdd, removing the first few lines of each file.

Is this actually possible?

I'd appreciate any help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: thank you for editing hasumedic

Comment: You can use `filter()` transformation to remove these rows if they all have same structure in common.

Comment: suppose all files constain: 3 or 4 lines of data how to filter it!

Comment: Preprocess the files, outside spark.

Comment: i too thought of doing it outside spark, but is there any process to do it inside spark?

Comment: just because you have a Spark-hammer doesn't mean your problem is a nail.

Comment: how to remove it outside spark. for all files

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lets assume there are 2 files.

```
ravis-MacBook-Pro:files raviramadoss$ cat file.csv
first_file_first_record
first_file_second_record
first_file_third_record
first_file_fourth_record
first_file_fifth_record
first_file_sixth_record
ravis-MacBook-Pro:files raviramadoss$ cat file_2.csv
second_file_first_record
second_file_second_record
second_file_third_record
second_file_fourth_record
second_file_fifth_record
second_file_sixth_record
second_file_seventh_record
second_file_eight_record
```

Scala Code

```
sc.wholeTextFiles("/Users/raviramadoss/files").flatMap( _._2.lines.drop(5) ).collect()
```

Output:

```
res41: Array[String] = Array(first_file_sixth_record, second_file_sixth_record, second_file_seventh_record, second_file_eight_record)
```

Comment: thanks @Ravi. you are collecting the headers of each file into RDD but how to remove it and load only records into RDD

Comment: the first five records from the file is not in the RDD. Check the Array in output. Assuming those first 5 are the header, they are not in the RDD.

Comment: BTW `.split("\n")` can be replaced with `.lines`, returned type is slightly different (`Iterator` vs `Array`) but I think it isn't a problem. Cheers.

Comment: oh! sorry i missed it @RaviRamadoss once again thank you! bingo

Comment: @TomaszBłachut edited as per your suggestion to use lines. Thanks!!

Answer (score -1):

In Spark/Hadoop if you give the input path as the directory containing all the files then the code which you have written will work on all the individual files separately.

So to achieve your objective, just give the input path as the directory containing all the files. So the first few lines will be removed from all the files.

Comment: We can also do it using:                                                                        scala> val file = sc.textFile("file:///root/path/file*.csv") for same column names in all files

Comment: But your problem statement is to do it for multiple files. So i have suggested this!

Comment: thank you – Kiran Krishna Innamuri, how to achieve second problem?

Comment: @KiranKrishnaInnamuri, no, it won't, according to my understanding. It will run once, on the result of loading all the files. `textFile` returns a single RDD, and so the mapPartition code will remove 5 lines from the first partition. It won't remove 5 lines from each file.

Comment: taking header as one rdd and filtering:                                               scala>val  data = filedata.filter(x => x != header).... i tried this but its not working can you do this and try ??

Comment: val header = sc.parallelize(List("line1","line2","lineN")) as my header rdd